# ATmega: wake up ATmega with external RTC

Tags: atmega, sleep-mode, real-time-clock

I'm working on a data logger which should safe as much as possible battery life. Therefore the logger (the chip ATmega 328P) is put to sleep and everything work just fine. Now I want to extend the setup with an RTC module (DS3231) to have the time information to every measurement taken.

Now my question: how can I wake the chip by the external RTC or is it just not possible. What I found out is that the chip, even in power-down-mode, can be woken up by an external event. But I did not find a way how to do that using the RTC. It might be interesting that the logger is set up to take measurements once in a hour.

Thanks for every hint!

(PS: For all the super heros out there, before you start down-voting my question: YES I'm worthless and I'm to stupid being allowed to ask any question BUT I DON'T CARE!)

Comment: The DS3231 has a INT/SQW signal which you can program and tie to an pin change interrupt on the MCU (open-drain, so don't forget the pull-up). Alternatively you may want to switch off regulator/supply entirely, letting the RTC interrupt wake it again

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned in the comments you could use the INT/SQW signal to wake up your ATmega regularly via an external interrupt. The DS3231 RTC module's INT/SQW signal can be triggered by one of two built-in time/date alarms ([DS3231 datasheet](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS3231.pdf)):

> The alarms can be programmed (by the alarm enable and INTCN bits of the control register) to activate the INT/SQW output on an alarm match condition.

The steps required for triggering the DS3231's interrupt signal every full hour are

- clear register 0x0B (Alarm 2 Minutes) (including mask bit `A2M2`)
- set the mask bit `A2M3` (Bit 7 in 0x0C)
- set the mask bit `A2M4` (Bit 7 in 0x0D)
- enable Alarm 2 by setting `A2IE` (Bit 1 in 0x0E)
- enable DS3231 interrupt signal by setting `INTCN` (Bit 2 in 0x0E).

This will pull the INT/SQW pin low every full hour. Alarm 1 could just as well be used instead but would require one additional register to be set.

Configuring the ATmega's interrupt INT0 or INT1 to trigger on low level should do the trick.

From the [ATmega 328P datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc8161.pdf) section 12:

> Low level interrupt on INT0 and INT1 is detected asynchronously. This implies that this interrupt can be used for waking the part also from sleep modes other than Idle mode.